# Relational database not showing properly

Tags: php, database

Im working on an assignment and i created a database. The main database part works fine but the relational database isnt working. It doesnt seem to parse in the subject_id in

```
<?php
//2. Perform database query
$query = "SELECT * "; 
$query .= "FROM pages ";
$query .= "AND subject_id = {$subject["id"]} ";
$query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
$page_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

confirm_query($page_set);
?>
```

Here are the complete codes:

```
<?php include("header.php");?>

<div id ="main">
  <div id ="navigation">
   <ul class="subjects">
<?php
//2. Perform database query
$query = "SELECT * "; 
$query .= "FROM subjects ";
$query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
$subject_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

confirm_query($subject_set);
?>
<?php
//3 Use returned data (if any)
while($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set)) {
?>  
   <li>
     <?php echo $subject["menu_name"] . " (" .$subject["id"] . ")";
?>   
<?php
//2. Perform database query
$query = "SELECT * "; 
$query .= "FROM pages ";
$query .= "AND subject_id = {$subject["id"]} ";
$query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
$page_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

confirm_query($page_set);
?>
<ul class="pages">
<?php
//3 Use returned data (if any)
while($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_set)) {
?>  
   <li><?php echo $page["menu_name"]; ?></li>
<?php
}
?>
<?php
//4. Release returned data
mysqli_free_result($page_set);?>
</ul>

</li>

   <?php
}
?>
<?php
//4. Release returned data
mysqli_free_result($subject_set);?>
</ul>


</div>
<div id="page">
<h2> Manage Content</h2>

</div>
</div>
<?php include("includes/footer.php");?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line

```
$query .= "AND subject_id = {$subject["id"]} ";
```

to:

```
$query .= "AND subject_id = {$subject['id']} ";
```

remenber you need a `WHERE` to use a `AND` clause:

```
SELECT * pages AND subject_id = {$subject["id"]} ORDER BY position ASC
```

change to:

```
SELECT * pages WHERE subject_id = {$subject["id"]} ORDER BY position ASC
```

use prepared statement is safer!

```
$query = "SELECT * pages WHERE subject_id = ? ORDER BY position ASC";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query);
mysqli_bind_param($stmt, i, $subject['id']);
mysqli_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
```

Comment: Yep, it works now. I didn't know you need a where clause to use a AND clause. Thanks for pointing that out. The tutorial video indeed uses a WHERE clause which i excluded out as it did not fit my database. 

I have not learnt how to use prepared statements yet. Might have to learn it soon. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$subject["id"]
```

with

```
$subject['id']
```